# How to draw tiled map in Android studio with libgdx

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, tiled, tmxtiledmap

```
mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader ();
map = mapLoader.load ( "saa.tmx" );
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer ( map );
```

My error is :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: saa.tmx
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like libGDX can't find the file.

- Is the path correct? (It starts in your "anroid/assets" folder)
- Maybe try using `Gdx.files.internal("saa.tmx")` or rather `Gdx.files.internal("saa.tmx").path()`